# Parsing an unnamed element in beautifulsoup

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, beautifulsoup, lxml

I need to parse certain text between unnamed br elements, for a certain class name's span. In this example, I need the 0.36, which is right after a named attribute "DS" in this example.

Here's what I tried.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
html="""
<pre5 style="">                                                    
    <br><br>
    <span class="field-name">DS :</span>                               
    0.36 [null]<br><br> <br> <span> <b>FC</b> </span><span> : 0.0 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>FDC</b> </span><span> : 0.36 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>LDD</b> </span><span> : 4838400000 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>IFS</b> </span><span> : 0.5333333 </span><br> 
  </pre5>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
divTag = soup.find_all("pre5", {"style":""})

for tag in divTag:
    tdTags = tag.find_all("span", {"class":"field-name"})
    for tag in tdTags:
        print tag.text 
        # print DS :, but I want 0.36


#Alternatively,
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print str(soup.span.next_sibling.strip()).replace('[null]','')
#prints 0.36 , but I would like to print by making sure that this element actually comes along with DS: and not just by the "immediate next sibilng" - is there a way to respect the named attribute DS and fetch the value for it ?
```

Also parsing/splitting/replace it via string, will be slower, can I use the tree structure directly ?

**Edit**, the value should be 0.007 for DS in this case. It is not assured that DS will be the first element in the span class.

```
html="""
<pre5 style="">                                                    
    <br><br>
    <span class="field-name">FC :</span>                               
    0.36 [null]<br><br> <br> <span> <b>DS:</b> </span><span> : 0.007 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>FDC</b> </span><span> : 0.36 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>LDD</b> </span><span> : 4838400000 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>IFS</b> </span><span> : 0.5333333 </span><br> 
  </pre5>
"""
```

Answer (score 2):

As the text `DS` can either be inside a `<span>` or  a `<b>` tag, also the data can be inside a `<span>` tag, you can search for the tags like this:

```
html = """
<pre5 style="">
    <br><br>
    <span class="field-name">DS :</span>
    0.36 [null]<br><br> <br> <span> <b>FC</b> </span><span> : 0.0 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>FDC</b> </span><span> : 0.36 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>LDD</b> </span><span> : 4838400000 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>IFS</b> </span><span> : 0.5333333 </span><br>
  </pre5>
<pre5 style="">
    <br><br>
    <span class="field-name">FC :</span>
    0.36 [null]<br><br> <br> <span> <b>DS:</b> </span><span> : 0.007 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>FDC</b> </span><span> : 0.36 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>LDD</b> </span><span> : 4838400000 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>IFS</b> </span><span> : 0.5333333 </span><br>
  </pre5>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
divTag = soup.find_all("pre5", {"style": ""})

import re

for tag in divTag:
    tdTags = tag.find_all(["span", "b"], text=re.compile(r'DS\s*:'))
    for tag in tdTags:
        if tag.nextSibling.strip():
            print tag.nextSibling.replace('[null]', '').strip()
        else:
            print tag.findNext("span").text.replace(':', '').strip()
```

This will give you output:

```
0.36
0.007
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you said that the text you want to extract is just right after the `<span>` tag, so you could use `next_element` twice. The first one for the text inside the tag and the second one for the text after it. It seems to work here, like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  
html="""
<pre5 style="">                                                    
    <br><br>
    <span class="field-name">DS :</span>                               
    0.36 [null]<br><br> <br> <span> <b>FC</b> </span><span> : 0.0 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>FDC</b> </span><span> : 0.36 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>LDD</b> </span><span> : 4838400000 </span><br>  <br> <span> <b>IFS</b> </span><span> : 0.5333333 </span><br> 
  </pre5>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
divTag = soup.find_all("pre5", {"style":""})

for tag in divTag:
    tdTags = tag.find_all("span", {"class":"field-name"})
    for tag in tdTags:
        print tag.next_element.next_element.replace('[null]', '')
```

It yields (with some blanks that could be removed afterwards):

```
0.36
```

Comment: Your code still assumed that span class="field-name">DS : will come first. Can you edit this to ensure that if DS: was the second in the span class, we will still get the right float for "DS"

Comment: @ekta: I don't get the new `xml` data with your explanation. Could you edit your question and add it to check in what way my solution does not fit?

Comment: @Birel Please see Edit above

Comment: @ekta: It seems that [salman wahed](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1113211/salman-wahed) got it, so check his solution first.